# "interrupt function contains function calls" gcc error

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, interrupt, riscv

In my code I get this

> "error: interrupt function contains function calls: ***foo***"

when compiling with the toolchain: `riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc (gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC))`

but not with this toolchain `riscv32-corev-elf-gcc (gcc version 11.0.0 20200813 (experimental)`

Having function call in ISR could be bad but that is not the point, I can't get rid of legacy.

How could I disable this error?

in my code I have defined interrupt using:

```
__attribute__((interrupt))
```

could this be the cause? not supported attribute?
when I remove the attribute, the error disappears, so I'll need to have prologue/epilogue sequences in assembly I guess

but this is strange because it says it supports it:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RISC-V-Function-Attributes.html#RISC-V-Function-Attributes

could it exist any gcc flag that could disable this error?

note: hard to have a minimal reproducible example as there is no gcc riscv compiler < 8.0 on godbolt.com

Comment: Show us the code and the exact commands used to compile.

Comment: gcc version 5.2.0 is *old*. It is almost as old as risc-v itself. Just don't use it, it is probably containing many other "childhood" issues (specific to risc-v) .

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well, it's from 2015. Compared to the age of the gcc compiler, that's a pretty recent release.

Comment: see post edit : I can't reproduce the error on godbolt because former risc-v gcc is 8.5

Comment: @Lundin: A lot of embedded work uses old compilers.  Many compilers have teething pains, but once a compiler "stabilizes", I think versions that add new features are more likely to have bugs than the versions which focused on fixing existing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

using `gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)`,
you are not allowed to have the attribute keyword with the interrupt declaration, only with the interrupt definition.
BUT, that SHOULD not be used, because epilogue/prologue are not well generated, so interrupt won't work, you'll have to manually write a generic epilogue and prologue for all irqs.